# 2D Collision from a single direction?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I've been learning Unity a bit and while I have managed to make my player sprite collide with the ground using a `OnCollisionEnter2D` function:

```
private void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D collision) {
    if (collision.gameObject.tag == "Ground") {
      isGrounded = true;
    }
  }
```

If I run with the player and collide with an object with the ground tag, it assumes the player is grounded because of collision. Is there a way to limit OnCollisionEnter2D to involve a single direction? i.e., when the player falls so that the system can interpret it as being on the ground (the bottom of the player against the top of a ground object)

Comment: You can keep the y coordinate in a class variable in the `Update` to check if the player is falling and conditionally update the `isGrounded` variable. However I don't understand the purpose/need of your question as the geometry limits of the colliders and their layout are the ones that work as the direction constraint

Comment: A simple solution could be tocompare the y value of both objects (if player is above ground then isGrounded = true).

Answer (score 0):

Look for [collision.GetContacts](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Collision.GetContacts.html) documentation. It returns all points, which collide with your collider.

Usage example:

```
private void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D collision)
{
    ContactPoint2D[] allPoints = new ContactPoint2D[collision.contactCount];
    collision.GetContacts(allPoints);

    foreach (var i in allPoints)
    {
        Debug.Log(i.point);
    }
}
```

If all `i.point.y < transform.position.y`, then you collide with ground

Answer (score 0):

So I ended up borrowing Adrien G.'s comment and checked the bounds of colliders like so:

```
private void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D collision) {
    Collider2D collider = collision.collider;
    Collider2D otherCollider = collision.otherCollider;

    if (collision.gameObject.tag == "Ground") {
      if (otherCollider.tag == "Hero") {
        if (!isHorizontalCollision(otherCollider, collider)) {
          isGrounded = true;
          isFalling = false;
          isJumping = false;
          horizontalCollision = false;
        } else {          
          horizontalCollision = true;

          if (isBottomCollision(otherCollider, collider)) {
            horizontalCollision = false;
          }
        }
      }      
    }

    collisionCounter++;
  }
```

Since my player has the `Hero` tag, I made sure to limit access to the vars through it. Horizontal collision grabs the bounds of each collider:

```
private bool isHorizontalCollision(Collider2D collider1, Collider2D collider2) {
    int c1RightEdge = (int) collider1.bounds.max.x;
    int c1LeftEdge = (int) collider1.bounds.min.x;

    int c2RightEdge = (int) collider2.bounds.max.x;
    int c2LeftEdge = (int) collider2.bounds.min.x;

    return (c1RightEdge == c2LeftEdge) || (c1LeftEdge == c2RightEdge);
  }
```

This means that if the bounds of each match either left or right, a horizontal collision is taking place and thus player shouldn't be marked as grounded or not falling nor jumping anymore. But since in my case I am using this for horizontal movement:

```
float horizontalInput = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
.
.
.
body.velocity = new Vector2(horizontalInput * speed, body.velocity.y);
```

the hero would still move, as if trying to dig through a horizontal object colliding against. So I would encase the velocity change in a block:

```
if (!horizontalCollision) {
      body.velocity = new Vector2(horizontalInput * speed, body.velocity.y);
      .
      .
      .
```

But this would freeze the hero after falling to the ground, so it wouldn't be able to walk unless it jumps and falls without a horizontal collision. To fix this, I implement a `isBottomCollision` function:

```
private bool isBottomCollision(Collider2D collider1, Collider2D collider2) {
    int c1BottomEdge = (int) collider1.bounds.max.y;
    int c2TopEdge = (int) collider2.bounds.min.y;

    return c1BottomEdge == c2TopEdge;
  }
```

which is basically the same as the horizontal collision, but to check the player's bottom edge against the collider's top edge. If they match, then the collision is from the bottom and thus the horizontalCollision boolean is set to false, enabling the hero to run again.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Collision.relativeVelocity to achieve that.

To check if the player collided with the floor from the top assuming that the floor is static in the y direction, you can check if the relative velocity of the collision between the player and the floor is lower then 0 in the y direction:

```
void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision)
    {
        if (collision.relativeVelocity.y < 0)
            //the collision came from the top 
    }
```

Have a look at:
https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Collision-relativeVelocity.html